# Is it possible to install TeamViewer Client on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, teamviewer, raspbian

Is it possible to install the TeamViewer client on a Raspberry Pi? I am running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. I currently have the host installed, but would like to connect from it as well.

I tried using the `.deb` package for Linux but it said:

> A package could not be found that allows this action to complete.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Of course, sorry I'll add that to my description. Duh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no *client* version of TeamViewer for ARM based devices.  The Raspberry Pi uses an ARM CPU.  This means there is no officially supported method for remoting into a Pi with TeamViewer.

Googling shows there are alternative methods, but I cant vouch for their effectiveness.